# How to make a click event stop once a successful discount code has been entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: The suggestion above is NOT the answer to this question. Please see tymeJV's answer.

I have an offer code field on my form but once it has been applied I want it to stop. Currently you can keep entering the offer code and it will keep discounting the price.

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edFqH/)**

How can I stop this happening?

```
$("#offerapply").click(function () {
if ($("input[name='offercode']").val().toLowerCase() == "discount10")  {
    price = (price / 10) * 9;
    $("#offermsg").text('Thank you. Your 10% discount has been applied.');
}
else {
    $("#offermsg").text('Sorry, that Offer Code was not recognised.');
}
calculate();
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Try using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: I would advise not using client side code to check for discount codes. Very insecure way to do this.

Comment: @JohnFx - The script is just for displaying the total price. It's not sending the price to the server.

Comment: This needs to be done on the server. Don't send the discount from the client, as I could tamper with the request to change the discount amount. Instead, send the coupon code and verify it on the server.

Comment: Do you care that anyone can view the source and see what the valid coupon codes are?

Comment: Looking forward to the "Why are my customers are getting 2000% discounts?" question.

Comment: Actually, anyone with the knowledge could take a look at your source code and know the code for the discount. This should be done on server sides as above mentioned.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat - I still need the button to work if they enter the wrong code to start with. I just want it to disable once they have entered the correct code.

Comment: @Jason P - no, the coupon code is clearly shown all over the website :-P

Comment: @asawyer - The script is just for displaying the toal price - nothing else

Comment: @Zeaklous - I dont want the button to be able to be only clicked once. If they enter the wrong code I need it to keep working

Comment: @Chris is almost impossible to type it wrong. They just have to Copy-n-Paste. Not rocket science there

Comment: @Zeaklous - I said once it has been applied I want it to stop

Comment: @Braiam - the offer is shown all over the website. They don't need to look at the source code

Comment: @Chris If the coupon code is displayed on the site why make them type it at all instead of giving them a dropdown?

Comment: @JohnFx - It's a sales technique. I think people are more likely to think they are getting something special if they have to enter a discount code

Comment: You shouldn't unbind the event handler or use one(), you should be doing it like [***THIS FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/edFqH/2/)

Comment: Dude keeps posting questions here asking people to write his code and you guys keep doing it.  Way to fight over repulation

Comment: @Zeaklous - Question title has been changed - thanks!

Comment: @adeneo - What's wrong with using $(this).off();

Comment: What if the user types a code, then decides to type another one, or remove the code, or do anything else at all really, the event handler is lost, and that's that. Of course if you only have one discount code, and once it's entered, it can't be undone, using off() works fine, but IMO it's bad UX to design stuff like that, where the user can't undo, even if you would thing the user wanted a discount, it's annoying with stuff that "once it done, it's done" !

Comment: Also, discount codes should be stored on the serverside, and looked up, not directly in the page source.

Comment: @adeneo - there's only one discount code - so no need to worry about that. I can't see why anyone would want to remove the discount :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `if` true block, unbind it to prevent multiple discounts:

```
if ($("input[name='offercode']").val().toLowerCase() == "discount10")  {
    price = (price / 10) * 9;
    $("#offermsg").text('Thank you. Your 10% discount has been applied.');
    $(this).off();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to the **[one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** jquery method. So you can try this piece of code :

```
$("#offerapply").one('click', function () {
    // your code here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need it to keep working if they enter the wrong code

Answer (score 1):

### **[Demo - Approach #1](http://jsfiddle.net/vu4E7/1/)**

```
$('a.remove_item').on('click',function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
   $('a.remove_item').off('click');
});
```

### **[Demo - Approach #2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_one)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#offerapply").one('click', function () {
        // your code here
    })
});
```

### **[Demo - Approach #3](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5PhHk/1/)**

```
$.fn.liveAndLetDie = function(event, callback) {
    var sel = this.selector;
    function unbind() { $(sel).die(event, callback).die(event, unbind); }
    return this.live(event, callback).live(event, unbind);
};
```

​

```
$('your elements').liveAndLetDie('click', function(e) { /* do stuff */ });
```

### **[Demo - Approach #4](http://jsfiddle.net/vu4E7/)**

```
$('your element').live('click',function(e) {
     $('your element').die('click'); // This removes the .live() functionality
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is just to store whether or not an offer code has been applied, but as mentioned, make sure you are also doing server side validation.

```
var offercodeApplied = false;

$("#offerapply").click(function () {
if (offercodeApplied) {
    $("#offermsg").text('Offer code already applied.');
}
else if ($("input[name='offercode']").val().toLowerCase() == "discount10")  {
    offercodeApplied = true;
    price = (price / 10) * 9;
    $("#offermsg").text('Thank you. Your 10% discount has been applied.');
}
else {
    $("#offermsg").text('Sorry, that Offer Code was not recognised.');
}
calculate();
```